# Magento2 - Why no cache memory on Content->Widgets grid view in admin panel?

Tags: magento2, cache, full-page-cache

In most Magento Admin grid view, they can remember admin user searching params even if they quit that page.

For example: Stores-> All stores page

But in Content->Widgets page, it is not available to cache the memory.

So how can I reactive this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. Content->Widget is created by Layout not ui component. Therefore, the setting need to defined inside the xml file.

In this case, ***adminhtml_widget_instance_block.xml*** will define the setting for the widget page grid view. We need to rewrite this xml to finish the task.

Add ***save_parameters_in_session*** argument.

```
<arguments>
    <argument name="save_parameters_in_session" xsi:type="string">1</argument>
</arguments>
```